# React Native FS readFile returns invalid path for iOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, camera-roll, react-native-fs

I have the functionality to `readFile` using [RNFS](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) library and [CameraRoll](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-cameraroll) of **React Native**.
Here is my code below:

```
const base64Image = await RNFS.readFile(uri, 'base64');
```

It's working fine for **Android** but not in **iOS**.

Here is the error for iOS below:

> err: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> 'ph-upload://02FA9ADA-FD03-43EF-A2B7-9DEDC9DC4AC6/L0/001'

Appreciate if someone could help. Thanks